# arp table entry outside configured network

Tags: linux-networking, arp

Can someone tell me why do I have arp table entry outside interface network?

Server has 2 interfaces, both on the same network:
eth0 10.10.34.146/22
eth1 10.10.33.188/22

ip route
default via 10.10.32.2 dev eth0  proto static  metric 1024
10.10.32.0/22 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.10.34.146
10.10.32.0/22 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.10.33.188

arp -n
Address HWtype HWaddress Flags Mask Iface
176.119.32.2 ether d4:d7:48:b5:a3:c1   C eth1
176.119.32.2 ether d4:d7:48:b5:a3:c1   C eth0

And then, when I ping 8.8.8.8 (from eth0) I get icmp reply but arp table does not change.
But when I ping **-I eth1** 8.8.8.8 I get icmp reply and there **is a new entry** in arp table:
**8.8.8.8 ether d4:d7:48:b5:a3:c1   C eth1**

But, when I add 'ip route add default via 176.119.32.2 dev eth1' to the routing table and ping 8.8.8.8 from eth1 there is no new arp table entry for 8.8.8.8.
Why is that?
Thanks.

NOTE: Both interfaces are connected to Cisco switch with 'ip local-proxy-arp' on the SVI with ip 176.119.32.2/22 which is default gw, and both are in Private VLAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the Cisco interface your eth0 is connected to is configured with `ip local-proxy-arp` but the Cisco interface your eth1 connects to is actually configured with `ip proxy-arp` instead.  This would account for the switch taking responsibility over the data-link addressing of an IP outside of the locally configured LAN.

Can you please verify this on the switch configuration?  If I am incorrect, please post the results of `show run int [PORT_FOR_ETH0]` and `show run int [PORT_FOR_ETH1]`?

Comment: Well... the server is VMware virtual machine which is connected via vDS with private vlan to Cisco. I did't write this info, because I think it is irrelevant. And on Cisco is only `ip local-proxy-arp`.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Everything is correct.
If there is no default gateway configured on the interface and there is proxy-arp configured on switch port, then if you ping ip address outside network configured on the iface, you will get arp entry in your arp table with ip address outside current network.
Thats the normal behaviour :].
I've checked this manually on lab switch.